# Hide input button depending on usergroup Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I hope you are all well.

I'm trying to understand thymeleaf in cooporation with java spring boot, but having a hard time with it.

I'm trying to hide a button in my navigation bar depending on usergroup.
I've tried the following:

```
<form action="/adminMemberList" method="post">
  <input th:if="@{${user.usergroup == '0'}}" type="submit" value="MEMBERS" class="cand-head1">
</form>
```

I've also tried using "eq" instead of "==". If I try to print the users usergroup it works fine.
Do anyone have any idea?

Best regards!

Comment: try using th:if="${user.usergroup == 0}" instead.

Comment: @RAGINROSE ah, your comment got me on other thoughts, i believe it was because it was a varchar in my database. not sure why i made it a varchar in the first place, tho. But thanks!

Comment: if it is varchar th:if="${user.usergroup == '0'}" this should work.

Comment: @RAGINROSE yes, that was my thoughts, but I believe I had been looking at it for too long, as I made it varchar in my database, but an integer in my model. So I believe if I changed either one to match the other, it would work. I'm just glad you got me on other thoughts :) Cheers